# How does "Exile and return to battlefield" work with a Manifest

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am playing [Brago, King Eternal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrago%2c%20King%20Eternal%5d) as my Commander and I have a [Cloudform](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCloudform%5d) attached to a Manifested card. What will happen if I use Brago's trigger (exile permanent and return to the battlefield) on both Cloudform and the Manifest?

Will the Manifest be revealed? Will it be flipped? If so, what happens if the Manifest is an instant/sorcery?

Please reference the rules when answering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first two questions are a duplicate of this [question.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/20530/does-exiling-a-morph-card-face-down-for-the-turn-bring-it-back-face-up) (Yes revealed.  Yes flipped)

For your third question, it won't return from exile:

> 304.4. Instants can’t enter the battlefield. If an instant would enter the battlefield, it remains in its previous zone instead.
>
> 307.4. Sorceries can’t enter the battlefield. If a sorcery would enter the battlefield, it remains in its previous zone instead.

Comment: It's good to see that rule 307.4 gets *some* use besides preventing Splintering Wind shenanigans.